# Wrong Encryption (QT c++ OpenSSL AES 256 CBC)

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, aes, cbc-mode

I wrote a small program to encrypt and decrypt data using OpenSSL AES 256 CBC but after decrypting the encrypted data I ended up with garbage data so there must be something wrong in the code but I couldn't figure it out can you please take a look at the code and tell me what I did wrong :

Main function :

```
  /* Message to be encrypted */
    unsigned char* plaintext =
                (unsigned char*)"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

  EVP_CIPHER_CTX *en, *de;
   en = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
   de = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();

    /* 8 bytes to salt the key_data during key generation. This is an example of
       compiled in salt. We just read the bit pattern created by these two 4 byte
       integers on the stack as 64 bits of contigous salt material -
       ofcourse this only works if sizeof(int) >= 4 */
    unsigned int salt[] = {12345, 54321};
    unsigned char *key_data;
    int key_data_len, i;

    key_data = (unsigned char*)"01234567890123456789012345678901";
    key_data_len = strlen((const char*)key_data);

    Encryption AES;

    /* gen key and iv. init the cipher ctx object */
    if (AES.Init(key_data, key_data_len, (unsigned char *)&salt, en, de)) {
      qDebug() << "Couldn't initialize AES cipher ";
    }

      unsigned char *ciphertext;
      int olen, len;

      /* The enc/dec functions deal with binary data and not C strings. strlen() will
         return length of the string without counting the '\0' string marker. We always
         pass in the marker byte to the encrypt/decrypt functions so that after decryption
         we end up with a legal C string */
      olen = len = strlen((const char*)plaintext)+1;



      ciphertext = AES.Encrypt(en, plaintext, &len);
      plaintext = (unsigned char*)"";
      plaintext = AES.Decrypt(de, ciphertext, &len);

      QString s;
      QString result = "";
      int rev = strlen((const char*)ciphertext);

      for ( int i = 0; i<rev; i++)
           {
              s = QString("%1").arg(ciphertext[i],0,16);

              if(s == "0"){
                s="00";
               }
            result.append(s);

            }

      ui->label_7->setText(result);

      rev = len;
      result = "";
      for ( int i = 0; i<rev; i++)
                     {
                        s = QString("%1").arg(plaintext[i],0,16);

                        if(s == "0"){
                          s="00";
                         }
                      result.append(s);

                      }

      ui->label_8->setText(result);

      free(ciphertext);
      free(plaintext);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(en);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(de);
```

Init function :

```
int Encryption::Init(unsigned char *key_data, int key_data_len, unsigned char *salt, EVP_CIPHER_CTX *e_ctx,
             EVP_CIPHER_CTX *d_ctx)
{
  int i, nrounds = 5;
  unsigned char key[32], iv[32];

  /*
   * Generate key & IV for AES 256 CBC mode. A SHA1 digest is used to hash the supplied key material.
   * nrounds is the number of times we hash the material. More rounds are more secure but
   * slower.
   */
  i = EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), salt, key_data, key_data_len, nrounds, key, iv);
  if (i != 32) {
    QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Error while generating the key"), tr("The key isn't 256 bit!"));
    return -1;
  }

  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(e_ctx);
  EVP_EncryptInit_ex(e_ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(d_ctx);
  EVP_DecryptInit_ex(d_ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);

  return 0;
}
```

Encrypt function :

```
inline unsigned char* Encryption:: Encrypt(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *e, unsigned char *plaintext, int *len)
{
  // max ciphertext len for a n bytes of plaintext is n + AES_BLOCK_SIZE bytes
  int c_len = *len + AES_BLOCK_SIZE, f_len = 0;
  ciphertext = new unsigned char[c_len];

  // allows reusing of 'e' for multiple encryption cycles
  EVP_EncryptInit_ex(e, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  /* update ciphertext, c_len is filled with the length of ciphertext generated,
    *len is the size of plaintext in bytes */
  int encrypted_bytes = 0;

  for(int i=0;i<*len/AES_BLOCK_SIZE;++i)
  {
      EVP_EncryptUpdate(e, ciphertext+encrypted_bytes, &c_len, plaintext+encrypted_bytes, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
      encrypted_bytes += AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
      float counter = i , size = *len/AES_BLOCK_SIZE+1;
      emit Encryption_Percentage_Changed(counter/size * 100);
  }
  // update ciphertext with the final remaining bytes
  EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(e, ciphertext+*len, &f_len);

  *len = *len + f_len;

  emit Encryption_Finished();

  return ciphertext;
}
```

Decrypt function :

```
inline unsigned char* Encryption::Decrypt(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *e, unsigned char *ciphertext, int *len)
{
  // plaintext will always be equal to or lesser than length of ciphertext
  int p_len = *len+AES_BLOCK_SIZE, f_len = 0;

  plaintext = new unsigned char[p_len];

  EVP_DecryptInit_ex(e, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  int decrypted_bytes = 0;

  for(int i=0;i<*len/AES_BLOCK_SIZE;++i){
      EVP_DecryptUpdate(e, plaintext+decrypted_bytes, &p_len, ciphertext+decrypted_bytes, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
      decrypted_bytes += AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
      float counter = i , size = *len/AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
      emit Decryption_Percentage_Changed(counter/size * 100);
  }

  EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(e, plaintext+*len, &f_len);


  *len = *len + f_len;

  emit Decryption_Finished();

  return plaintext;
}
```

Edit: I have replaced the images with actual code now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ideally you would provide the code in one big block anyway so others can copy paste it and compile and run it with a minimal amount of work. So don't forget to add the includes which are needed for compilation. BTW others with enough reputation can edit your question so if you don't succeed in formatting it correctly someone else can fix that for you.

Comment: @Eelke Thanks so much for the info but the code compiles fine it is not a compile error that I face , it is a logic error.because when I encrypt a text and try to decrypt it I don't get the original text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I realized what was the problem it was in displaying the encrypted and decrypted strings when I tried result=QString::fromLocal8Bit((char*)ciphertext);
it worked fine and showed the original text.